# find('count') find('all') combination

Tags: php, cakephp

I've a code below to find all the list of students

```
$fub = $this->Customer->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Customer.customers_types' => 'student')));
```

I've a code below to count the number of student who attempted the test.

```
$totalTests = $this->Customer->Test->find('count', array('conditions' => array('Test.customer_id' => $fub['Customer']['id'])));

$this->set('totalTests', $totalTests);
```

However, I've more than one customer that is student. How can I use the result from $fub and chuck it into the $totalTests condition to get the total number of of student who attempted the test.

Debugger::dump($fub);

```
array(
    array(),
    array(),
    array(),
    array(),
    array(),
    array()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should likely be using [ [CakePHPs counterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto) ].  It keeps track of the count of related items for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your count query the conditions which you try may not be match and return the array empty

```
$fub['Customer']['id']
```

is empty. first debug the $fub before your count query.
the way which i follow is to set the

```
$fub['customer']['id']
```

into a variable, like that

```
$f = $fub['customer']['id']
```

before your count query
and the put this variable in your condition

```
$totalTests = $this->Customer->Test->find('count', array('conditions' => array('Test.customer_id' => $f)));
```

Try this one.